# Is it possible to change the content of captured packet before forwarding it to the destination?

Tags: networking, network-programming

I was wondering, if its possible to change the content of packets that captured from network before forwarding them to the destination?
I have an idea to intercept packets from programs and look for some specific values in their transmitted data. After replacing those data forward them to the destination.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You describe a "[Man in the middle attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack)", which yes, under certain conditions, is possible.

Comment: I know in MITM is possible to capture the packets, but I was not sure if its practical to change the content before sending to the destination.. In case this is possible. How about encrypted data? If I decrypt them, is it possible to change and encrypt them?

Comment: I wouldn't say practical in most cases. It is possible, and it is done (for example NA(p)T does it... But I sense your are looking to alter data that would be much easier / better to alter at the source.

Comment: [Network Address and Port Translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation).... Routers do it, altering each packets headers. But once again, I sense that this is the wrong direction...

Comment: The program that I have plan to write is a security app for Android, and I plan to run it on non-root apps. Therefore the only place which we can trap traffic which come outs of other apps is on the network. Because the access to source of traffic on not rooted phones is not possible.